# I need a condition in jquery to find whether a div inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a condition in jquery to find whether an element focussed in div is inside a particular div.I need it on the keydown event

I tried the following code

```
$('.menu-toggle').on("keydown", function(e) {

    $(document.activeElement).isChildOf('.menu-wrap.closed')
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu-wrap closed">
<input></input>//I need to know if this element gets focussed then whether it is inside menu-wrap closed I cant use this input elements focus event or anything directly
</div>
```

Edited question

Comment: provide `HTML` also.

Comment: `if($(document.activeElement).parents('.menu-wrap.closed').length)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

**UPDATE:** If you want to know where the focus is when you click somewhere, you should listen to mousedown event.

```js
$("#clickme").on("mousedown", function(e){
  if($(document.activeElement).parents('#foo').length > 0){
    alert("Focus on foo child");
  }
  else{
    alert("Focus somewhere else");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"><input class="myInput" type="text"/></div>
<div id="bar"><input class="myInput" type="text"/></div>
<button id="clickme">CLICK</button>
```

Comment: I cant use the input keydown which I have specified in my question

Comment: the focus is on another element outside this

Comment: I cant use the focus and keydown events because I am clicking tab button the focus goes to a element inside the menu-wrap-closed now on that elements keydown I need to check

Comment: I think that finally I got what you want. Check the update.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the class of the parent:

```js
$('.menu-toggle').on('keydown', function() {
  if ($(this).parent().attr('class') == 'menu-wrap-closed') {
    alert('inside');
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-wrap-closed {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid silver;
}
.menu-toggle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-wrap-closed">
  <input class="menu-toggle">
</div>
<input class="menu-toggle">
```

Comment: menu-toggle is outside the div with class named menu-wrap-closed

Comment: I cant use the focus and keydown events because I am clicking tab button the focus goes to a element inside the menu-wrap-closed now on that elements keydown I need to check

Comment: OK - that's why it helps to post your HTML.  This was not clear in your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/).
Then check if the parent is the one with the class.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `.closest()` and see if it brings any matches

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if( $(document.activeElement).closest('.menu-wrap.closed').length ){
       // it is a child of the .menu-wrap.closed element
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure expected behaviour is to include element itself. But i guess it doesn't really matter

Comment: @ᴀʀᴜnBᴇrtiL But why not just checking for `if( $(this).closest('.menu-wrap.closed').length )`??? Because anyway the keydown event can only be fired on focused element if not triggered programatically. Or you could use `$('.menu-wrap.closed :focus').length`

Comment: @ᴀʀᴜnBᴇrtiL can you provide (*in your question*) the relevant html and what/when exactly you want to run the test ? Also why can't you use the `focus` and `keydown` events ?

Comment: menu-toggle is outside the div with class named menu-wrap-closed

Comment: I cant use the focus and keydown events because I am clicking tab button the focus goes to a element inside the menu-wrap-closed now on that elements keydown I need to check

Comment: @ᴀʀᴜnBᴇrtiL then try with the updated version where you check the `keydown` on the `document` element (*since all such events will bubble to the document*)